# Connecting Android Phone and Laptop via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I'm beginning to use Bluetooth in my apps and want to be able to send data from my phone to my laptop over this connection. I have to use Bluetooth as I will eventually be sending this data directly from my phone to a robot which can only be accessed via Bluetooth. 
Unfortunately, I cannot connect my laptop and my phone. My phone is showing that it is paired with my laptop but my laptop show's no connections. My phone does show up on my laptop but when I tell it to connect to it I get this error: "Connection has been denied by PAN server [Nexus S].
Any input as to what I can do to fix this is greatly appreciated. My phone is running ICS 4.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you install a custom Serial Port over Bluetooth application on your Android phone and let it try to connect to your laptop. [There are plenty of free apps out there](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=serial%20port%20profile&c=apps).

You are not connecting to your laptop because the phone does not know what profile (part of Bluetooth) you want to connect.

Bluetooth connections are server-client connections and can have multiple purposes(sending data, sending audio, controlling the Bluetooth link, etc.

Ultimately you will probably use [SPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Serial_Port_Profile_.28SPP.29) over [RFCOMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFCOMM#Radio_frequency_communication_.28RFCOMM.29) for connecting to your robot. It would help if your laptop's bluetooth chip driver and application handled(accepted) this type of connections. If not, you can do your own fast PC app using [PyBluez](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/) for example.
Try and find out.

Don't forget to vote if helpful!